# Groovy multi-methods

Tags: methods, groovy, overloading

I started learning `Groovy` and got curious about its method invocation resolving. I've read and understand what is groovy multi-methods, but I can't understand behaviour of next code snippet

```
def method(int i) {
    println 1
}

def method(Number n) {
    println 2
}

Number n = 1

method n            # returns 1 as expected
method((Number) n)  # returns 2 which I can't understand why
```

Is there some exclusion about casting? Can someone please explain this behaviour?

Comment: by `method((Number) n)` you are forcing to call method with `Number` parameter.

Comment: It seems so. is it documented somewhere?

Comment: it's obvious... no? what could be other logic?

Comment: For me it is not obvious at all, because groovy determine which of overloaded method to invoke in runtime by object class. By doing casting we don't change object type

Comment: You can think about cast as changing reference type in runtime. You can also see "Otherwise, at run time, the operand value is converted (if necessary) by casting conversion to the target type specified by the cast operator. " in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.16 . In groovy "as" keyword can be used also. Groovy dispatch methods call using runtime types.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you see here is a result of value in-/out-boxing.

If you pass a value of actial type `Integer` in, the value is converted to `int` during method lookup and the 1st method is called.

If you cast the value to `Number` or it's sub-class explicitly the inboxing does not happen and the method expecting `Number` is invoked.

I extended your code a bit:

```
def method(int i) {
    println "int > $i / ${i.getClass()}"
}

def method(Number i) {
    println "Number > $i / ${i.getClass()}"
}

def method(float i) {
    println "float > $i / ${i.getClass()}"
}

Number n = 1
Number nFloat = 1.0f
Number nDouble = 1.0d

method n
method( new BigInteger( n ) )
method( (Number)n )
method( new BigInteger( n ) as int )
method nFloat
method nDouble
```

prints

```
int > 1 / class java.lang.Integer
Number > 1 / class java.math.BigInteger
Number > 1 / class java.lang.Integer
int > 1 / class java.lang.Integer
float > 1.0 / class java.lang.Float
Number > 1.0 / class java.lang.Double
```

Hope it is getting clearer now...

Comment: It's not the matter of auto-boxing. It's reproducible for non primitive types as well

Comment: In groovy by default there are no primitive types, what my example explicitly shows